# Ganglia Web does not show status of other nodes, only shows the meta node. Possible reasons?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, monitoring, ganglia, gmetad

I have 3 machines in my HDFS cluster: `pr2` is the meta node, and `pr1` and `pr3` are the other 2 nodes. I want to monitor them with `ganglia web`. To that end, `Ganglia` (with both `gmetad` and `gmond`) has been installed on all 3 nodes, and `ganglia web` has been installed on the meta node, `pr2`.

I am running the following:

On pr2:

```
service gmetad start
service gmond start
service httpd start
```

On pr1 and pr3:

```
service gmond start
```

I expect to see in `ganglia web` information about all 3 nodes. But this is what I see:

[image]

Only 1 node seems to be running, which is `pr2`.

What could be the reason?

I have explored the following possibilities when configuring the setup:

1. In the gmond configuration file, there is a place to specify the "host machine". What should be the "host" here? For example, for node `pr1`, should it be the local machine (`pr1`), or the meta node (`pr2`)? I have tried with both `pr1` and `pr2` separately, and I still can't see info of `pr1` or `pr3` on `ganglia web`. Also, do I need to add anything more in this section?

`[root@pr1]# nano /usr/local/etc/gmond.conf`

```
/* The host section describes attributes of the host, like the location */
host {
  location = "unspecified" ### Should I replace "unspecified" with pr2 (the meta node), or with pr1? ###
}
```

2. Also, in the same configuration file, there is a section for configuring `udp_send_channels`. There is a parameter `mcast_join`, which I think is to specify the meta node. So I changed the IP to `pr2`. But since `ganglia web` is not showing info of `pr1` and `pr3`, I tried changing it to `pr1` and `pr3` respectively, but to no avail.

`[root@pr1]# nano /usr/local/etc/gmond.conf`

```
udp_send_channel {
  #bind_hostname = yes 
  mcast_join = 239.2.11.71 ### Should I change this IP to pr2 or pr1? ###
  port = 8649
  ttl = 1
}
```

3. Again, in the same file, there's a section for configuring `udp_recv_channel`. I have commented out the `mcast_join` and `bind` here, since I thought the `pr1` and `pr3` nodes do not need to receive any info from anything, they only need to send info to the meta node, `pr2`. Am I wrong?

`[root@pr1]# nano /usr/local/etc/gmond.conf`

```
udp_recv_channel {
  #mcast_join = 239.2.11.71
  port = 8649
  #bind = 239.2.11.71
  retry_bind = true
  # Size of the UDP buffer. If you are handling lots of metrics you really
  # should bump it up to e.g. 10MB or even higher.
  # buffer = 10485760
}
```

4. Then I run the following smoke test:

`gmond -d 5 -c /usr/local/etc/gmond.conf`

and it returns the following (showing the tail part of the long output):

```
...
...
Counting device /dev/mapper/centos-root (2.69 %)
Counting device /dev/mapper/centos-home (0.02 %)
Counting device /dev/sda1 (18.49 %)
For all disks: 206.174 GB total, 204.498 GB free for users.
    metric 'part_max_used' has value_threshold 1.000000
    sent message 'heartbeat' of length 48 with 0 errors
Processing a metric value message from pr1.embs
Got a heartbeat message 1511171541
```

This means that `gmond` is working correctly, am I right?

5. Then I configure the `gmond` init file (for calling the command), and make the following 2 changes: (i) point `GMOND` to the correct path, and (ii) point the daemon to the correct path of the `gmond.conf` file. Could I possibly be doing anything wrong here?

[root@pr1]# nano /etc/init.d/gmond

```
### Change here ###
#GMOND=/usr/sbin/gmond
GMOND=/usr/local/sbin/gmond

# TMPDIR set to SysV IPC ramdrive to avoid include processing failures
TMPDIR=/dev/shm
export TMPDIR

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

start() {
    [ -x $GMOND ] || exit 5
    [ -f /etc/ganglia/gmond.conf ] || exit 6
    echo -n "Starting GANGLIA gmond: "

    ### Change here ###
    #daemon $GMOND
    daemon $GMOND -c /usr/local/etc/gmond.conf
```

6. Then I modify the `gmetad.conf` file to change the `datasource` and add the cluster name and the user name. Here, should I change the datasource to the local machine (`pr1` or `pr3`), or to the meta node (`pr2`)?

`[root@pr1]# nano /usr/local/etc/gmetad.conf`

```
===(change)
data_source "edhcluster" pr1 ### Should I change this to pr2, the meta node?
===

===(add)
gridname "edhcluster"
===

===(add)
setuid_username "ganglia"
===
```

Or, an even bigger question, should I not change anything in this file of the nodes `pr1` and `pr3` (as only `pr2` is the meta node that will monitor everything), and instead change the `gmetad.conf` file of the meta node, `pr2`, only to include in its `datasource` all the 3 nodes, like so:

`[root@pr**2**]# nano /usr/local/etc/gmetad.conf`

```
data_source "edhcluster" pr1 pr2 pr3
```

But then, I read somewhere a little while ago while browsing to solve this problem, that writing the names of the nodes like this means that it'll first check pr1, if it is down it'll check pr2, and if that is down too, it'll check pr3. So, if we want to make it collect data from all 3 machines, we should write separate lines for each node, like so:

`[root@pr2]# nano /usr/local/etc/gmetad.conf`

```
data_source "edhcluster" pr1
data_source "edhcluster" pr2
data_source "edhcluster" pr3
```

I tried this as well, and then restarted all the services in all the nodes (`gmetad`, `gmond` and `httpd` in `pr2`, and `gmond` in `pr1` and `pr3`), but ganglia web still doesn't show anything for the other 2 nodes.

7. Then I modified the `gmetad.init` file (for calling the command) on `pr1` to make the `GMETAD` daemon point to the correct path of the `gmetad.conf` file. However, I suspect this might be wrong, as the `gmetad` of `pr2` should handle this. So, am I correct in identifying this as the mistake? If yes, how do I make the gmetad daemon point to the path of the config file in another node, the meta node, `pr2`?

`[root@pr1]# nano /etc/init.d/gmetad`

```
### Change here ###
#GMETAD=/usr/sbin/gmetad
GMETAD=/usr/local/sbin/gmetad

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

test -f /etc/sysconfig/gmetad && . /etc/sysconfig/gmetad

export RRDCACHED_ADDRESS

start() {
    [ -x $GMETAD ] || exit 5
    [ -f /etc/ganglia/gmetad.conf ] || exit 6
    echo -n "Starting GANGLIA gmetad: "

    ### Change here ###
    #daemon $GMETAD
    daemon $GMETAD -c /usr/local/etc/gmetad.conf 
    ### If this means that the gmetad of the local system 
    ### will monitor this node, how do I make the daemon 
    ### point to the gmetad.conf file of the meta node, pr2?

    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/gmetad
    return $RETVAL
}
```

Thanks for going through all the details of the configuration steps. If I missed or overlooked any other possible causes, please feel free to point them out.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:apache-spark] ?

Comment: @eliasah Because Ganglia can monitor spark nodes as well. So someone who's trying to setup monitoring of spark services who is/has also facing/faced this issue can see this thread.